# Dropped the Distibution database before disabling publishing and distribution, how to proceed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication

I'm setting up my first *Distributor* database on SQL Server 2012.  I successfully created one and then wanted to blow it away and perform the task again just for practice.

This was a brand new distributor and nothing had been done with it yet.

In my naivete I ran the the following commands before disabling the publishing and distribution:

```
alter database distribution set offline;
drop database distribution;
```

Now when I try to disable it, I get the following error:

```
SQL Server could not disable publishing and distribution on '<server>'.
------------------------------
Database 'distribution' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
Changed database context to 'master'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 911)
```

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the advice in [Accidentally Dropped the Distribution Database](https://web.archive.org/web/20130119063350/http://www.sqlrepl.com/sql-server/accidentally-dropped-distribution-database/) by Brandon Williams:

> Whatever you do, don’t panic.  Dropping the distribution database this way isn’t good but we still have the distribution data and log files files located in the folder we specified when configuring distribution.  The reason these files are still around is because when a database is offline and is dropped, the disk files are not deleted.  Knowing this, all we need to do is attach the distribution data and log files to recreate the distribution database.

> If you encounter access denied errors when attaching the distribution data and log files, grant appropriate permissions to the distribution.mdf and distribution.ldf files on the Security tab in the file properties dialog.  This will circumvent the access denied errors.

> After attaching the distribution data and log files, the distribution database should now be in a workable state.  Existing publications should resume as normal and if you choose to do so, publishing and distribution can now be disabled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The good thing is that you offlined the database and then dropped it. So, the files will be around. Just attach them and you will be good to go.

Always backup your database before doing anything like modifying, dropping, etc.

Also, the Knowledge Base article [INF: Replication: How to Rebuild the Distribution Database](https://web.archive.org/web/20150120042517/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190797) describes the steps if you don't have the files as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have been the same issue faced and I used the below delete command and tried to remove the Distribution.

select * from msdb.dbo.MSdistpublishers

delete from msdb.dbo.MSdistpublishers