# How to disable replication when Distribution db is lost?

Tags: sql-server, replication, disaster-recovery

I am in the situation that the Distribution database in SQL Server 2014 is lost and I want to disable the replication. I have found a [solution how to achieve that when data files are present](http://www.sqlrepl.com/sql-server/accidentally-dropped-distribution-database/) (also [asked here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/58624/81045)). Unfortunately, I do not have data files of Distribution database. Is it possible to disable the replication when Distribution database is completely lost?

Comment: Do you have a good restorable backup of distribution database ? If yes, you can restore that with KEEP REPLICATION. If not, then you have to clean up replication bits from replication tables.

Comment: I was not backing up the distribution database, since it does not contain critical data. (However, it was not easy for me to find, how to disable the replication when the distribution database is lost.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution. Problem was that I was calling the stored procedures from query windows of Management Studio (some stored procedures must be called from `sqlcmd`).

Then, it is enough to follow [instructions for TSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151759.aspx#Anchor_2) (with `@no_checks` and `@ignore_distributor`).